# svg fonts: max. glyphs contained (large font)

Tags: svg, fonts

I have a special case in which I have nearly 200.000 different glyphs which I want to create as font. SVG would be best for my use.

How much glyphs can a SVG font contain? Are there limits for the glyphs or for other things?

Does a font format exist which would be better for my plan?

Comment: What research did you do before asking your question on SO?  The section on fonts in the SVG specification can be found here: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/fonts.html

Comment: I have read many websites, also this svg specification from w3.org but I could not find something about glyph limitation or something. Otherwise I wouldnt have asked this question ;)

Comment: AFAIK there is no limit. But be aware that SVG fonts are now deprecated. Most browsers never supported them. Chrome once did, but has now removed its support. So the number of places you will be able to use them is now very small. http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-fonts

Comment: Thanks! I will only use it for myself and not in the web, so the lack of browser support doesnt matter.

Comment: also note that SVG fonts, as a technology, is really really dead. It turned out to be a bad idea because is made actual typography (with proper GPOS/GSUB tables etc) *really* hard - Fonts got *huge*. So most browsers have stopped supporting SVG fonts again (Safari being a notable exception, but you don't want to target a single browser). What you really want is just a font stack with several WOFF fonts to cover the range you need, much like how NoTo and NoTo CJK do things. Even if it's "just for yourself". Better to make real fonts, because they're real.